# .net mvc selectlist multiple sources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I have a list of users I am retrieving from Active Directory like so

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN", "dc=domain,dc=org");
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Advisors");
ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(group.Members, "EmployeeID", "DisplayName");
```

I would like to add two additional items to this list but do not want to create user accounts for them in Active Directory as they are not real users.

Is it possible to do something like

```
var items1 = new[] 
{  
    new { EmployeeID = "1", DisplayName = "Independent" },
    new { EmployeeID = "2", DisplayName = "Own" }
};

var items = Concat(group.Members, items1);
{
    ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(items, "EmployeeID", "DisplayName");
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `group.Members`? You could cast to to an list of this type, add some objects to this list and bind it to the `ViewBag`.

Comment: Sorry @Felipe not sure what you mean.

Comment: Well, you can get the group.Members and add these two itens on this list, and set it to the `ViewBag` to see on the comboBox on the View. You cannot add anonymous type to a strongly typed list.

Comment: I don't believe it is strongly typed. Would you have an example of how to add additional items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You can have a [ViewModel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_model) like this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

and than you can cast the group.Members to a list of your ViewModel, add some custom itens on this list and set this list to the ViewBag.

```
var members = group.Members.Select(x => new EmployeeViewModel() { EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId, DisplayName = x.DisplayName }).ToList();

members.Add(new EmployeeViewModel() { EmployeeId = "1", DisplayName = "Independent" });
members.Add(new EmployeeViewModel() { EmployeeId = "2", DisplayName = "Own" });

ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(members, "EmployeeID", "DisplayName");
```

Comment: Thanks @Felipe. Almost there. The only problem with this is that EmployeeId is not available by GroupPrincipal but is by UserPrincipal. Do you know how to get round this?

Comment: Never mind! Got the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13609465/1472203 Thanks @Felipe for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Well, you can use a ViewModel to send to the View only the necessary. If a list is typed you cannot add anonymous type there. :)