# using GroupPrincipal can you get additional info from UserPrincipal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am looking up users who are members of an AD group using GroupPrincipal.

```
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Advisors");
```

I need to get the EmployeeID field from this lookup but I believe this is only possible using UserPrincipal.

```
var members = group.Members.Select(x => new DomainContext() { EmployeeID = x.EmployeeId, FullName = x.DisplayName }).ToList();
```

Does anyone know of a way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use UserPrincipal unless you're using the underlying DirectoryEntry/DirectorySearcher classes.

You should use .GetMembers() instead of .Members then you can do stuff like:

```
var userMembers = group.GetMembers().OfType<UserPrincipal>();
foreach( var member in userMembers) {
    string empid = member.EmployeeId; //do something with the EmployeeId
}
```